# Don't allow deletions on Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

If I wanted to not allow users to delete a file stored in Firebase storage, what rule would I need to write to accomplish this?

I know for Firebase database I would do something like:

```
".write": "newData.val() != null"
```

But how would I do this for storage?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this has been answered a few times (in a few ways), but the easiest answer I've seen is:

```
allow write: request.resource.someProperty == resource.someProperty || resource == null;
```

`someProperty` can be a hash (if you don't want to allow overwrites) or a name (if you want the contents to be overwritten by a new object).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to only allow writes if the MD5 hash of the new file is the same as the existing file:

```
// Allow writes if the hash of the uploaded file is the same as the existing file
allow write: if request.resource.md5Hash == resource.md5Hash;
```

There are probably more/easier ways. But this is the first one I came across in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/.

Comment: I think this doesn't allow writes in the first place (if the file doesn't exist)